# assigning an order ID to different rows of a table based on their Date Order and grouped by CustomerID in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a data set for products bought by each customer, I want to give an order to their transactions by sorting the date columns.

For example :

```
 SubID           Date                        other columns          OrderColumn  
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1                  2010/08/12                ......                      ?
   1                  2011/09/12                .......                     ?
   1                  2013/09/12                ......                      ?
   2                  2013/09/12                .......                     ?
   2                  2011/04/03                ......                      ?
```

I want to give an order to the transactions for each customer.

Something like this :

```
 SubID           Date                        other columns          OrderColumn  
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                  2010/08/12                ......                      1
  1                  2011/09/12                .......                     2
  1                  2013/09/12                ......                      3
  2                  2013/09/12                .......                     2
  2                  2011/04/03                ......                      1
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function:

```
SELECT
   SubID,
   [Date],
   OrderColumn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubID ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
FROM
   dbo.YourTable
```

This is "partition" your data by the `SubID` and each "partition" (or group of data) will get an incrementing number starting at 1 - based on the order date

(*Side note*: having a column called just `Date` is very unfortunate - first of all, it's not very descriptive... *what kind* of date are you talking about here? Furthermore, `DATE` is a reserved word (datatype) in SQL Server! You should strive to use something more meaningful - `OrderDate` or `DateCreated` or whatever makes sense in your situation)

Comment: Dear Friend, Thanks for your answer. It was a simplified example of my question. my real table is completely different.